# Cannot invoke value of map because possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

In my application I have a `Map` that returns a set of settings taking the role of the user as a key.

```
enum Role {
    ROLE_1 = "role"
}
const settingsRole1 = {}
const defaultSettings = {}
const secondParameter = ""

const map = new Map<Role, any>([
    [Role.ROLE_1, settingsRole1]
]);
const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1) ?? defaultSettings;
```

Now I want to introduce a second parameters. Since I want to modify the code as little as possible, I thought to transform the `Map<Role, Settings>` into `Map<Role, (secondParameter: string) => Settings>`, returning a function from the map, that will be invoked later.

```
enum Role {
    ROLE_1 = "role"
}
const settingsRole1 = {}
const defaultSettings = {}
const secondParameter = ""

const map = new Map<Role, (secondParameter: string) => any>([
    [Role.ROLE_1, (secondParameter: string) => settingsRole1]
]);
const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1)(secondParameter) ?? defaultSettings;
```

I receive this error while trying to calling the function returning from the map: `TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`.
I tried to guard it, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
enum Role {
    ROLE_1 = "role"
}
const settings = {}
const defaultSettings = {}

const map = new Map<Role, (secondParameter: string) => any>([
    [Role.ROLE_1, (secondParameter: string) => settings]
]);
const settings = map.has(Role.ROLE_1) ? map.get(Role.ROLE_1)(secondParameter) : defaultSettings;
```

I don't understand how to make the guard work, anyways I would consider trying other approaches if you want to suggest one

Comment: Thanks for providing a [mre].  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnB0eN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does indeed, but why `if else` doesn't work while `optional chaining` does?

Comment: Do you mean `map.has(x) ? map.get(x) : y`?  That doesn't work because `has` doesn't act as a guard; it's tricky to get that right (maps are mutable and there's no good way to make other methods "reset" the narrowing), see [ms/TS#13086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086).  I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining this, but the basic "use optional chaining" advice seems to be an answer already and so I'm concerned that that answer will be accepted instead of mine.  Tell me how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: In the question I asked for an explanation of why the `map.has(x) ? map.get(x) : y` approach doesn't work, so if you provide a more explanatory answer I'd be happy to read it and accept that

Comment: You might consider [edit]ing to make it clear that your primary question is the explanation for why it doesn't work.  I see "I don't understand" and I see "I would consider trying other approaches" and it's not clear if either of those are a question and which one would be the primary question.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't clear. What about I open a new question and I send the link in the comments?

Comment: Sure, whatever you want to do.  The "how to make it work" question seems to be what people are answering here, so the other question should probably be the "why doesn't it work" one.  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thouht to create a new question. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804861/why-map-has-doesnt-act-as-a-type-guard) if you want to answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining `?.` for first parameter

```js
const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1)?.(secondParameter) ?? defaultSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` after expression to tell compiler to ignore its nullability. In your case it should be (with explicit key check)

```
    const settings = map.has(Role.ROLE_1) ? map.get(Role.ROLE_1)!(secondParameter) : defaultSettings;
```

Alternative way is to use optional chaining `?.` operator

```
    const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1)?.(secondParameter) ?? defaultSettings;
```

but it's slightly different semantically - it doesn't distinguish between missing keys and keys with explicit `null` / `undefined` values.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but isn't using `optional chaining` semantically more correct, since I'm don't tell the compiler that the `key` is not in the `Map`, but I handle the case instead?

Comment: You might want to edit this to a version like `map.has(Role.ROLE_1) ? map.get(Role.ROLE_1)!(secondParameter) : defaultSettings`, since that's the only way this is safe.  Otherwise you're just ignoring the real possibility that it will be `undefined`